# How to change font color in HTML

Tags: html

I have a piece of text that I am trying to change the font color for on my site. The code is showing up correctly and I have read some other forums and tried to modify the code myself using HTML font color and PHP style but I can't seem to get it to work.

I am not a programmer myself, so I am most likely making some kind of rookie mistake. The code currently installed on the site is below:

```
<div style='text-align:center'>
<?php
  ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 3);
  echo file_get_contents('https://www.mysamplesite.com');
?>
</div>
```

I actually do not care if it is center aligned or not if I can get it to show up in white font, but I can't seem to be able to get it to show in white font.

When the sample code loads it brings back certain text that displays on the front of my my site. Can someone please tell me how to format this code properly to get it to show in a color of font of my choice? Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does `file_get_contents('https://www.mysamplesite.com')` return plain text or HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<div class="code">
  <?php
  ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 3);
  echo file_get_contents('https://www.mysamplesite.com');
  ?>
</div>

<style>
.code, .code *
{
  color: #FFFFFF!important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is a add a color declaration:

```
<div style='text-align:center; color: #FFFFFF;'>
```

Keep in mind that any inline style tags may overwrite the parent's style properties.

Comment: Thank you for tour quick response Jay. I did try your suggestion but it did not successfully change the color text. I am able to get it to align in the center with that same code though but not able to change the font color. The php command pulls an string of html from a third party site onto our site, not sure if that is relevant or not. Thanks again!

Comment: If the HTML has inline CSS *that* CSS will take priority as it is the last style info loaded.